# A job module that writes JSON to file instead of XML

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

I wrote a spring xd job module that exported from jdbc to xml. Several weeks ago. Was using Tuple as a data structure. Then using oxm to just write the Tuples to file.

```
<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="resource"
            value="file:${exportDir}/#{jobParameters['jobKey']}/#{stepExecutionContext['orderFileNamePrefix']}-#{stepExecutionContext['tableFileName']}.${exportFileExtension}" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="rootTagName" value="#{stepExecutionContext['tableFileName']}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller" scope="step">
        <property name="aliases">
            <util:map id="aliases">
                <entry key="#{stepExecutionContext['tableFileName']}" value="org.springframework.xd.tuple.batch.TupleFieldExtractor" />
            </util:map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The resulting xml was rather arbitrary. But there was no requirement for a specific xml schema.

Now I'm doing the import part, using json instead of xml as a flat file format is a new requirement. So I'm looking for the smallest change I can make to the export module so it writes out json instead of xml. In spring xd it seems this sort of application would be better implemented using sources, streams and sinks. But I'm now stuck with a job module because the system that integrates the UI with spring xd sets up definitions automatically through the REST API.

I would have thought working with Tuples and JSON would be pretty easy because of Spring's type conversion infrastructure. I just can't figure out how to implement in the spring xd job module context.

So in a job module, what type of writer should I use to write lists of Tuples to file using json as a format?
What reader should I use to read json files to lists of Tuples?

I'll admit there is much of spring xd I don't fully understand. Some direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building a Tuple using the Spring XD `TupleBuilder`, the `tupleToStringConverter` that is provided is one that will convert the current `Tuple` to a JSON String.  Because of that, to write the `Tuple` in JSON, all you would need to do is use the `FlatFileItemWriter` and the `PassThroughLineAggregator` which just calls `toString` on the object being written.  Keep in mind, this approach leaves you with a file where each line is a complete JSON object and the full file itself is not a valid JSON object.

On the reading side, I believe you need to do a bit of wrapping.  Spring XD provides a `JsonByteToTupleConverter` that takes a `byte[]` and converts it to a `Tuple`, but we don't provide a `LineMapper` that wraps it.  While I haven't tested it, I'd expect the following to work (assuming `line` contained a valid JSON string):

```
public class JsonToTupleLineMapper<Tuple> implements LineMapper<Tuple> {
    private Converter converter = new JsonByteToTupleConverter();

    @Override
    public Tuple mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
        return converter.convert(line.getBytes());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am curious though in the context of spring xd/or big data in general is this an odd implementation approach? Firstly is using a job rather then a source stream sink chain an atypical architecture? And is using flat files with a json object per line generally done or is it more like an obscure hack?

Comment: Using a job to handle bulk imports is a standard approach for big data.  Besides Spring XD, Sqoop is another example of where a job based approach for doing bulk imports is used.  With regards to the one JSON per line, I believe most big data applications would rather avoid the overhead of using JSON for an intermediate format like this and prefer to use things like delimited files.  Only if they are using it for object serialization would they use something like JSON.